# Updating from a paid app to a free app with In App Billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I want to release a new version of one of my paid apps, but now being free with In App Billing v2 integration.

The thing is, can I test the new version with test accounts? Under normal circumstances, for a brand new app, I would upload the APK as a draft and then test purchases from devices configured with test accounts, that's OK. But in this case when I try to test the app the famous "This version of the application is not configured for Market Billing" appears. Is that a problem related to the fact that the APK currently published in Google Play is v1 without In App Billing and in my device I have installed the v2 with In App Billing, despite the fact I have uploaded v2 with In App Billing as a draft?

Just to be clearer, my scenario is:

- I have currently published in Google Play the v1 of my app, that is a paid app.
- I have uploaded as a draft to Google Play a new v2 of my app, now free with In App Billing integration.
- I have installed in my device by hand that new v2 of my app.
- I can't test the app, because the "This version of the application is not configured for Market Billing" error appears.

Why? Because I have already published the v1 of the app that doesn't include In App Billing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the version and signature of the draft app and the one you are using for testing are the same. You also need to wait a few hours for the draft to become active. Not sure how well the paid->free transition is supported though, although it is supposed to work by setting the price to 0.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've done all that, as usual. My main problem is that I am not sure if the system let me check In App Billing with test accounts in this scenario.

Comment: Android documentation doesn't mention scenarios like this one (and it should)

Comment: I don't know. But the paid app probably doesn't change to free until you change the price to 0 and publish.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
the main reason you are getting the message is because you just uploaded your apk

you can check the android site: [Testing In App Billing](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html)

in point 3, you can see:

> Make sure that you have uploaded the signed APK for your application to the Developer Console, and associated one or more in-app products with your application. You don't need to publish the application on Google Play to test it.
>
> Warning: It may take up to 2-3 hours after uploading the APK for Google Play to recognize your updated APK version. If you try to test your application before your uploaded APK is recognized by Google Play, your application will receive a ‘purchase cancelled’ response with an error message “This version of the application is not enabled for In-app Billing.”

This is for V3 but I guess the part of recognizing the new apk stills the same

Comment: Thank you for answering. I waited those 2-3 hours and associated in-app products, as usual. I've done all this before, but I am facing problems now and I don't know if it is related to my particular scenario (updating from paid version to free/inapp version)